# How can I maintain a duplicate ordering of rows between two DataGrids of equal row count (and a hidden 1-1 mapping field)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two DataGrids that have the same number of rows. There is also a hidden integer field/column on each row for maintaining a 1-1 correspondence between the two. When the user sorts, selects, or scrolls, the action on one DataGrid needs to be replicated on the other. I am most concerned about sorting, since I'm afraid the DataGrid's sort operations may interfere or may not reflect my own ordering behind the scenes. What's the best way to maintain these views?

(It is for a surveying program in which one grid has a list of x,y,z coordinates and the second list has the same points with a transformation applied. These are split between two tabs for reasons of screen real-estate.)

Comment: On large datasets sorting may be expensive. If screen real estate is the issue you can have one datagrid with one type of items and switch the item template to switch between both views. This way screen estate is retained, sorting isn't done twice and you have a very reliable way of keeping the sort between both views in sync

Comment: "When the user sorts, selects, or scrolls, the action on one DataGrid needs to be replicated on the other."  Why can't you just use ONE data grid then?

Comment: @StenPetrov: Hmm, hadn't thought of that--one DataGrid with a two ItemTemplates is a great idea.

Comment: @BrianV: One data grid is fine if it can be refreshed with different columns, I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Having these both in the same table means making a new object that is a combination of Point, with both original and transformed values. I may end up doing it that way, but an answer to my question would have been nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On large datasets sorting may be expensive. If screen real estate is the issue you can have one datagrid with one type of items and switch the item template to switch between both views. This way screen estate is retained, sorting isn't done twice and you have a very reliable way of keeping the sort between both views in sync.

there are many ways to achieve the effect, the best approach depends on the specific circumstances.

One approach would be to set two different `<GridView>`s as resources and select which one is used either in code or through Binding with a custom converter:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <GridView x:Key="DefaultView">
             <GridViewColumn Width="120"....etc/>
        </GridView>
        <GridView x:Key="AlternativeView">
               <GridViewColumn Width="50"....etc/>
        </GridView>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayValues}" View="{StaticResource DefaultView}"/>

</Grid>
```

and in code behind you can switch the view, something like this:

```
   MyListView.View = isDefault ? MyListView.TryFindResource("DefaultView") :  MyListView.TryFindResource("AlternativeView")
```

It's also possible to use Binding and skip the code behind.

Another approach would be to make a user control for one of the column items where the user control can display the data in two alternative states.

Yet another possiblity is to use [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx)

Comment: "ItemTemplates" sounds marvelous except that you can only do cell templates to DataGridTextColumns, and there is nowhere I can bind a dynamic resource to change this "View" of the DataTable. I've tried making a converter that takes in the type of item in the collection and spits out the appropriate member of the item based on the tab they've chosen.

Comment: @StanPetrov:(cont'd...)But when I try to *bind* it, which is essential somewhere in this operation, an access to my ViewModel behind the scenes no matter what way you slice it (I can expand on that), I get the WPF error "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the (Converter, ConverterParameter, whatever} property, virtually anywhere I could possibly imagine I could bind something that would solve my problem. So the idea sounds better than it is in practice, unless you can see what I'm missing.

Comment: @StanPetrov: I'll try to make a DependencyProperty of the converter and set it in the resources

Comment: @BrandonArnold there are many ways, idk the specifics of your app, but see edit for suggestions

Comment: @StanPetrov: I'm still verifying this and will be happy to put a check if and when it actually works, but I should say that any way that doesn't retain the current scroll position, sort order, and current cell selection of the table, and also that does not allow dynamic switching of views behind the scenes, is not going to cut it. But I'm still cracking at it.

Comment: @BrandonArnold I'm certain it would work but there are too many ways to do it and I can't be more specific without seeing your app. Best of luck!

Comment: @StanPetrov: Thanks, Stan. I had to fall back on changing the columns' Visibility property, but the result is that I am using a single DataGrid and the scroll location and ordering are retained. I wasn't able to do so using a ViewModel, though, because the Visibility parameter doesn't update upon PropertyChanged("VisibilityParameter") for some reason. But since I'm doing it in the code-behind anyway, it should be easy to replicate the selected rows that are lost upon visibility switching. Thanks, again.